# Find the latest Eclipse for JDK 1.5

Tags: eclipse, java-5

What's the latest Eclipse version which supports JDK 1.5? In other words, Min JDK Requirement for Europa - min JDK Version Ganymede - min JDK Version Galileo - min JDK Version Helios - min JDK Version Indigo - min JDK Version Juno - min JDK Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Prerequisites

As Per today "Indigo" is latest version that can run on JDK1.5

Answer (score 2):

When you create a project, select JDK 1.5 instead of the standard 1.7. Your program will run on a 1.5 platform, and will be compatible with 1.5.

Your question sounds rather vague, so this is the best I can do with as much information as I have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Here my question is not that.
Min JDK Requirement for 

Europa - min JDK Version
Ganymede - min JDK Version
Galileo - min JDK Version
Helios - min JDK Version
Indigo - min JDK Version
Juno - min JDK Version